# How to Cleanup a Large Array of Repetitive "Nth-Of-Type" CSS Selectors?

Tags: css, css-selectors, code-cleanup, non-repetitive

Given: a simple array of colourful highlights, controlled in CSS only.

Is there any way, to shorten the following huge block of CSS code, while keeping the same outcome?

In other words is there a way to get rid of the amount of ***repeatability*** in the code, using only CSS, when selecting multiple `nth-of-type` declarations?

````
//CSS
nav:hover mark:nth-of-type(01){background:linear-gradient(to left, transparent, rgb(192 0 192 / 1))}
nav:hover mark:nth-of-type(02){background:linear-gradient(to left, transparent, rgb(180 0 250 / 1))}
nav:hover mark:nth-of-type(03){background:linear-gradient(to left, transparent, rgb(220 0 250 / 1))}
nav:hover mark:nth-of-type(04){background:linear-gradient(to left, transparent, rgb(220 0 120 / 1))}
nav:hover mark:nth-of-type(05){background:linear-gradient(to left, transparent, rgb(210 0 130 / 1))}
nav:hover mark:nth-of-type(06){background:linear-gradient(to left, transparent, rgb(202 184 0 / 1))}
nav:hover mark:nth-of-type(07){background:linear-gradient(to left, transparent, rgb(230 196 0 / 1))}
nav:hover mark:nth-of-type(08){background:linear-gradient(to left, transparent, rgb(145 190 0 / 1))}
nav:hover mark:nth-of-type(09){background:linear-gradient(to left, transparent, rgb(135 182 0 / 1))}
nav:hover mark:nth-of-type(10){background:linear-gradient(to left, transparent, rgb(0 204 227 / 1))}
nav:hover mark:nth-of-type(11){background:linear-gradient(to left, transparent, rgb(0 187 253 / 1))}
nav:hover mark:nth-of-type(12){background:linear-gradient(to left, transparent, rgb(0 192 212 / 1))}
nav:hover mark:nth-of-type(13){background:linear-gradient(to left, transparent, rgb(0 167 255 / 1))}
nav:hover mark:nth-of-type(14){background:linear-gradient(to left, transparent, rgb(0 165 150 / 1))}
nav:hover mark:nth-of-type(15){background:linear-gradient(to left, transparent, rgb(12 156 23 / 1))}
nav:hover mark:nth-of-type(16){background:linear-gradient(to left, transparent, rgb(16 20 162 / 1))}
```
````

Comment: Use a preprocessor like Sass instead

Comment: *while keeping the same outcome?* --> show us the outcome, maybe we can do it differently without all these codes

Comment: @TemaniAfif  Good point! Though I usually paste a picture or jsfiddle, I thought the outcome for my specific scenario (some gradient color highlights) is less interesting and kept the question to the point and consice. I wanted my question to be for all the generally "highly repetitive and painstakenly time consuming CSS code moments" and am very happy with the answer given A Haworth since it solves the general repetitive CSS coding problem, when SASS is out of reach.

Comment: if you show us the output you may get surprised with how you can achieve it with a different code that will probably be even shorter than the below answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For pure CSS you'll still need quite a bit of repetition but this is a bit more readable, using a CSS variable:

```
nav mark:nth-of-type(01){--c: rgb(192 0 192 / 1)}
nav mark:nth-of-type(02){--c: rgb(180 0 250 / 1)}
nav mark:nth-of-type(03){--c: rgb(220 0 250 / 1)}
nav mark:nth-of-type(04){--c: rgb(220 0 120 / 1)}
nav mark:nth-of-type(05){--c: rgb(210 0 130 / 1)}
nav mark:nth-of-type(06){--c: rgb(202 184 0 / 1)}
nav mark:nth-of-type(07){--c: rgb(230 196 0 / 1)}
nav mark:nth-of-type(08){--c: rgb(145 190 0 / 1)}
nav mark:nth-of-type(09){--c: rgb(135 182 0 / 1)}
nav mark:nth-of-type(10){--c: rgb(0 204 227 / 1)}
nav mark:nth-of-type(11){--c: rgb(0 187 253 / 1)}
nav mark:nth-of-type(12){--c: rgb(0 192 212 / 1)}
nav mark:nth-of-type(13){--c: rgb(0 167 255 / 1)}
nav mark:nth-of-type(14){--c: rgb(0 165 150 / 1)}
nav mark:nth-of-type(15){--c: rgb(12 156 23 / 1)}
nav mark:nth-of-type(16){--c: rgb(16 20 162 / 1)}

nav:hover mark:nth-of-type(n){background:linear-gradient(to left, transparent, var(--c))}
```

Comment: Tricky. Great / Elegant solution. That's why I am here for. Thx for showing it.

Comment: Ecellent! That is one readable solution! I learned something new today! And by the look of it, using variables in this way in CSS should be compatible across all browsers today https://caniuse.com/?search=css%20variables